# Find the matrix of T with respect to the standard bases for M2x2 and P2

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, linear-transformations

Let $T$: $M_{2x2}$ → $P_2$ be defined by $T$$\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ = $(a+b-c-d)t^2+(c+d)t+(a+b)$.

Find the matrix of $T$ with respect to the standard bases for $M_{2x2}$ and $P_2$.

To start, one thing that confuses me about this problem is the format that T is in. Can anyone help me interpret T before continuing to solve this?

Comment: How do you mean format of T, if you mean matrix format then you find the dimension of domain and codomain. If the dimension of codomain is m and dimension of domain is n then your matrix will be $\ T_{mxn}$

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps better notation would be $T\left( \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} \right) = (a+b-c-d)t^2 + (c+d)t + (a+b) $.

$T$ is a function. The matrix $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$ is the input of $T$. The output of $T$ is the polynomial $(a+b-c-d)t^2 + (c+d)t + (a+b)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $T(A)$  can be defined in the following form 
$$ \begin{bmatrix} t^2 + 1 &&-t^2 -t \\\end{bmatrix} A \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

The standard basis of $\mathcal M_{2,2}$ is
$$E_{1,1}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\enspace E_{1,2}=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\enspace E_{2,1}=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}, \enspace E_{2,2}=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}. $$ 
You have to find the  $3\times4$ matrix with first column the coordinates of $T(E_{1,1})$, second column the coordinates of $T(E_{1,2})$, &c.